# Merge weighted random sampled set with different distributions

Tags: probability, statistics, sampling, sampling-theory

Here is my problem:

I have a set $S_1$ of $N$ items each item i attached to a weight $w_{1_i}$. From this set I sample a subset of m items $(m << N)$ using weighted random sampling with replacement.

Then I have a set $S_2$ of $M$ items in which some items of $S_1$ may be included but with a different weight $w_2$.

I want now to sample a subset of $n (n > m)$ items from $S2$ doing a random weighted sampling with replacement but I want to keep the items that are in $S1 ∩ S2$ and have been previously picked.

My question is, how should these items be included in order for my new subset to follow accurately the weight distribution of the set $S2$?

My thinking was, to include the k items that are in $S1 ∩ S2$ with a count of $c_i$ = $w_{2_i} * m$ and complete them with a random weighted sampling of $m - sum(c_i)$ items in $S2$ - {k items}.

Does that sound like a reasonnable way to do it?

Comment: I am not sure I follow. You took a sample from $S_1$, not you want to take a sample from $S_2$. What kind of products are you talking about in the third paragraph?

Comment: sorry I meant items (these items are actually products in my application case but it does not matter here)

Comment: You can't do this in general because the first selection might already have a higher probability of generating items in $S_1\cap S_2$ than you want for your second distribution to hold. (By the way, are you aware that your post contains formatting errors?)

Comment: @joriki I agree but that's my question, is there a way to adjust the count of the items picked in the first distribution? If m >> N I would assume that adjusting the count of these products to c_i as defined above should do the trick since it's the number of items that we expect to pick asymptotically. However I'm not convinced that this holds when m < N ..